# Custom ComboBox Column for DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, datagridcomboboxcolumn

We have a Custom ComboBox working on a form that displays some shapes instead of text. To do that all I had to do was to override the OnDrawItem function and it displays what we want. Here is a snippet for reference:

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnDrawItem(e);

    e.DrawBackground();
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
        Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.LightGray);

        int size = this.Height/2;
        int origenX = e.Bounds.X + 1;
        int origenY = e.Bounds.Y + 3;
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path =
                new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
        switch (e.Index)
        {
            case 0:                            
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, origenX, origenY, size, size);                            
                Rectangle r = new Rectangle(origenX, origenY, size, size);                            
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, r, Color.Black,
                                        ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
                break;
            case 1:
                path.AddEllipse(origenX, origenY, size, size);
                e.Graphics.FillPath(brush, path);
                e.Graphics.DrawPath(Pens.Black, path);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you add that to a form and add a couple of items to your collection all you see is a square and a circle in the drop down.

Ok, so, what I want to do now is add this same combo box to a DataGridView. I know that this control has a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I was trying to extend the control, however, I don't see this OnDrawItem function to override. I guess there exists something similar?
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to interperet the DataGridViewComboBox as your custom Combobox.

```
private void dgTest_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgTest.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0) // Which column ever is your DataGridComboBoxColumn
            {
                // This line will enable you to use the DataDridViewCOmboBox like your
                // Custom ComboBox.
                CustomComboBox combo = e.Control as CUstomComboBox;

            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! unfortunately, no this does not do it. I did try that first. there are two problems with this solution, one is that it only shows the data in the items which basically is IDs in my case. Second, once, you exit edit mode it does not show anything because the table per se does not know what to draw.