# How to create ColorComboBox and bind its ValueMember to Color property of my class object?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am creating Windows Form Application, that should allow user to select color property of objects via ComboBox. Objects of type MyClass are stored in separate list, which is binded to one ComboBox. This ComboBox shows object ID.

PictureBox shows color of currently selected object via binding as well. These bindings are doing well, but I struggle to bind color property of MyClass object to ValueMember property of ComboBox.

This ComboBox has the list of all System.Drawing.Color colors (as text items for now). I need to bind current selection to MyClass.cr property. How to do that?

I also want to draw rectangles filled with correspondent color instead of text items in ComboBox. Should I use owner draw combobox, or is there simpler way?

Here is the code:

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    List<MyClass> MyClassList = new List<MyClass>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Create the list of objects typof(MyClass)
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            MyClassList.Add(new MyClass(i));

        // Set BindingSource
        MyClassBindingSource.DataSource = MyClassList;
        // Add bindings to ComboBox with IDs
        SelectIDComboBox.DataSource = MyClassBindingSource;
        SelectIDComboBox.DisplayMember = "ID";

        // Show color of current ID in special PictureBox
        ShowColorPictureBox.DataBindings.Add("BackColor", MyClassBindingSource, "cr", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

        // Allow user to change color, selecting it from another ComboBox
        string[] colors = Enum.GetNames(typeof(System.Drawing.KnownColor));

        // ComboBox must show rectangles filled with corresponding color, not color names
        SelectColorComboBox.Items.AddRange(colors);// for now only color names
        // Bind selected color to MyClass.cr property
        //????
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int id) { ID = id.ToString(); }
    public Color cr { get; set; } = Color.Red;
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding:

```
SelectColorComboBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", MyClassBindingSource, "cr", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
```

Draw rectangles filled with correspondent color.
Set `DrawMode` property and subscribe to `DrawItem` event:

```
SelectColorComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
SelectColorComboBox.DrawItem += SelectColorComboBox_DrawItem;

private void SelectColorComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    var strColor = (string)comboBox.Items[e.Index];
    var knownColor = (KnownColor)Enum.Parse(typeof(KnownColor), strColor);
    var color = Color.FromKnownColor(knownColor);

    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(color))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y + 1, 30, e.Bounds.Height - 2);

    TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, strColor, comboBox.Font, new Point(e.Bounds.X + 30, e.Bounds.Y), color);
}
```

Comment: Great! All code works well! I used "SelectedItem" property of ColorComboBox  instead of "Text" for binding and it didn`t work. Do you know what is the difference?

Comment: Now I need to add ColorComboBox to DataGridView, preserving bindings. MyClass objects must be in the rows of  DataGridView which has column "cr", based on "MyClass.cr" property. User should have a possibility to change their colors using ColorComboBox. There is a similar question about custom ComboBoxes "[Custom ComboBox Column for DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822925/custom-combobox-column-for-datagridview)", but the answer to it doesn`t work, I tried it.

Comment: @Alexander - Ask another separate question about `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.

Comment: Here is my new question about DataGridViewComboBoxColumn [How to populate custom ComboBox in one DataGridView column?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626232/how-to-populate-custom-combobox-in-one-datagridview-column). Thank you again!