# Adding Different color to combobox list items based on item display members

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

Am binding my combobox with selected items from Db as follows

```
   DataTable Dt = CashCounterCls.GetAllCashCounterAll();           
            cmbcashcounter.DataSource = Dt;
            cmbcashcounter.ValueMember = "Counter_Id";
            cmbcashcounter.DisplayMember = "FullName";
```

i need to change the color of displayed item in the combobox based on the text it contain.
ie,if it contain "open" text with i need to show that list item in green color

Comment: You must use custom manual drawing. Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39589446/5045688).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov thank u for the reference.Let me try with it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After populating a combo box, you can check every item and convert its color.

You can try below code,

```
For Each i As ListViewItem In cmbcashcounter.Items
            If (i.Text = "open") Then
                i.ForeColor = Color.Green
            End If

 Next
```